# Replacement for java bitwise operator in objective c

Tags: objective-c, bit-manipulation, code-translation

How can I translate the following code to objective c? (Value is an int)

```
while (value != 0) {
    value >>>= 1;
```

And is there a general replacement for the >>> operator?

Comment: The `>>>` operator is basically an unsigned version of the `>>` operator.  In theory, if you use `>>` on an unsigned operand in C you'll get the effect of the `>>>` operator in Java (which has no unsigned data type >= 32 bits width).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation is not directly supported, so you need to use a mask. Depending on the size of your `value` variable, you need to pick a mask of a different size.
If `value` is `short`, use `0x7FFF`; if `value` is `long long`, use `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

```
while (value != 0) {
    value >>= 1;
    value &= 0x7FFFFFFF;
}
```

Alternatively, you can declare `value` as unsigned: then the regular shift-assign would not sign-extend the `value`. In fact, big part of the reason the `>>>` operator was added to Java is the absence of unsigned types in the language.

Comment: Updated my question, is there a general replacement for the >>> operator?

Comment: Does this mean that I can change: ((y >>> 1) + (x / 3)) & 0x1; to ((y >> 1 & 0x7FFFFFFF) + (x / 3)) & 0x1;

Comment: @danielbeard You need an additional pair of parentheses, just to be safe: `(((y >> 1) & 0x7FFFFFFF) + (x / 3)) & 0x1`. You should consider using an unsigned type instead, then it would be just `((y >> 1) + (x / 3)) & 0x1`.

Comment: It seems to me that if you were to cast `value` to unsigned you should not need the `&=` operation.  Never tried it, though.

Comment: @HotLicks I think you can do it with a cast as well to avoid using the mask, but it's probably better to use unsigned type throughout.